# Two Queries at once with data shared between them

Tags: mysql

I need to execute two different mysql queries. The main problem is that I need the second one to use data from the previous one but not interfere with me selecting the data out. Hard for me to explain but here is my current combined queries:

```
SELECT accounts.id, username, password, proxy.ip, proxy.port
    FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN proxy ON proxy.id = accounts.proxy_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO task 
    (taskID, account_id, transaction_id) 
    VALUES ("*Insert Pregenerated Number*", accounts.id, *Insert Pregenerated Number*)
```

As you can see from the previous query I need where it says accounts.ID to be of the previous account I just queried for. However I want this done in one go and to also output the above data in the first select to my program. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just [`INSERT .. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) ?

```
INSERT INTO task 
    (taskID, account_id, transaction_id) 
SELECT "*Insert Pregenerated Number*",accounts.id,"*Insert Pregenerated Number*"
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN proxy ON proxy.id = accounts.proxy_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Or store them as variables :

```
  DECLARE myvar DOUBLE;
  ...
SELECT accounts.id, username, password, proxy.ip, proxy.port
INTO @myvar,@myvar2,....
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN proxy ON proxy.id = accounts.proxy_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

And then use them.

**EDIT:** alternatively you can create a temp table containing this row, and use it as many times ad you'd like :

```
 CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS(
SELECT accounts.id, username, password, proxy.ip, proxy.port
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN proxy ON proxy.id = accounts.proxy_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: That may work but I need to get the values accounts.id, username, password, proxy.ip, proxy.port as stated in the first select outputted as a row.